# A D3D11_USAGE_STAGING Resource cannot be bound to any parts of the graphics pipeline

Tags: directx-11, hlsl

I'm trying to Create RWStrutruedBuffer with a  D3D11_USAGE_STAGING for cpu access

.

error: D3D11_USAGE_STAGING Resource cannot be bound to any parts of the graphics pipeline.

1. How can get the RWStrutruedBuffer from GPU to CPU? I need the result.thanks for every.
2. Should I Copy a  Resource with a D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT flag to a Resource with D3D11_USAGE_STAGING ,then read it form CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer just like step 2,I need to Copy resource to other resource that was created with a  D3D11_USAGE_STAGING flag,then use map with D3D11_MAP_READ,finally read it.

Comment: Generally note that the performance of read-back will limit the value of doing the computation on the GPU unless it's *very* computationally expensive on the CPU.